# Generic list not diplaying content in ViewBag

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc

I got a database that contains 2 strings a Name and a Score now i want to display this into my .net mvc project.
I do this by executing the following code:

```
 public ActionResult DisplayScore()
    {
        string connection = Properties.Settings.Default.MySqlConnectionString;
        MySqlConnection dbcon = new MySqlConnection(connection);
        dbcon.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd;
        cmd = dbcon.CreateCommand();

        cmd.CommandText = "select * from test.scores order by Score asc limit 10;";
        List<MemScore> ScoreList = new List<MemScore>();
        MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (rdr.Read())
        {
             ScoreList.Add(new MemScore { DBname = (string)rdr["Name"], DBscore = (string)rdr["Score"] });

            string FinalScore = ScoreList.ToString();
            ViewBag.Message = FinalScore;
        }
        rdr.Close();
        return View();
    }
```

The list `MemScore` contains 2 strings DBname and DBscore
but when i try to display the date from the generic list i get this result:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Game_Website.Model.MemScore]
```

Does anyone got a idea why i get this result and how i fix it?

Comment: What do you think `ScoreList.ToString()` is going to give you?

Comment: you tell me thats why im asking :3

Comment: First your not even returning a model to the view. And your `string FinalScore = ScoreList.ToString();` and `ViewBag.Message = FinalScore;` makes no sense - its inside the loop and you keep overwriting the value

Comment: Delete those 2 lines of code and use `return View(ScoreList);`

Comment: Do not change your question and invalidate the comments/answers that have been added (I have rolled back your changes). And if you did make those changes you  would not be getting that result!